How to configure JMS for RabbitMQ on Mac
I am using the RMQClient as a Cocoapod.
RabbitMQ is running in a Docker instance.
I have successfully managed to get the RabbitMQ running and I can now pass messages from one process to another.
However, I need to be able to receive messages from an existing JMS Host. I have the Username, Password, Host, Port and Queue name for that service.
I have installed the JMS Plugin for RabbitMQ, so I think I only need to know how to let RabbitMQ/JMS know where the Queue is, and how to connect to it.
How can I configure RabbitMQ and its JMS Plugin to listen to this external server?
I suspect it might be possible to define a Queue or a Connection in the RabbitMQ Management UI, but I have not found how to do that.
Or perhaps I can configure it in the RabbitMQ configuration files?
